# Apache behind pure ipv6 router + dynDNS only reachable via ipv6 proxy

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, ipv6

I have troubles setting up a webserver using Apache behind a router which only has a public ipv6 address.
I assigned my server via dynv6 a DNS name. The resulting address is http://second.test-game-server.dynv6.net/Game/
.However, so far only an ipv6 proxy such as http://www.ipv6proxy.net is able to load my website. Typing the address directly into a brwoser loads 15 seconds and returns a timeout. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can someone confirm my webserver is reachable or not? I get mixed messages from other people and scanning websites.

Answer (score 0):

`dig AAAA second.test-game-server.dynv6.net` gives back `2a02:810d:d00:1dd4:c90f:ebb:c082:276b`

`tcptraceroute6` on port 80 gives

```
 4  be4204.ccr21.par04.atlas.cogentco.com (2001:978:2:1b::49:1) 30.994 ms  29.994 ms  28.995 ms
 5  2001:978:3::46 (2001:978:3::46)  28.995 ms  82.985 ms  29.994 ms
 6  ae13-ucr1.pld.cw.net (2001:5000:0:49::2)  49.991 ms  51.991 ms  48.991 ms
 7  ae33-xcr1.fix.cw.net (2001:5000:0:23d::1)  50.991 ms  48.991 ms 
49.991 ms
 8  ae0-xcr1.bln.cw.net (2001:5000:0:15::2)  52.990 ms  50.991 ms  49.991 ms
 9  kabel-gw.bln.cw.net (2001:5001:800:1::2)  51.991 ms  49.991 ms  49.991 ms
10  2a02:8100:4:2::eb1 (2a02:8100:4:2::eb1)  50.991 ms  50.991 ms  48.991 ms
11  2a02:8100:4:2::78d (2a02:8100:4:2::78d)  62.989 ms  60.989 ms  61.989 ms
12  * * *         
13  2a02:8100:6:2::14:82 (2a02:8100:6:2::14:82) 62.989 ms  63.989 ms  61.989 ms
14  * * * 
15  2a02:810d:0:1a:ddd7:e196:1d5a:ee73 (2a02:810d:0:1a:ddd7:e196:1d5a:ee73)  70.987 ms  71.987 ms  76.986 ms
16  2a02:810d:0:1a:ddd7:e196:1d5a:ee73 (2a02:810d:0:1a:ddd7:e196:1d5a:ee73)  3072.472 ms !H  3066.473 ms !H 3075.471 ms !H
```

It is some kind of virtual machine or such? You seem to have routing issues on your end.

Also,  based on http://dnsviz.net/d/second.test-game-server.dynv6.net/WVGPdQ/dnssec/ it seems dynv6.net authoritative nameservers do not reply on TCP, which is absolutely bad. Ask them to fix that!